# What is the return code of a Interceptors

Tags: struts2

I am a new bud to struts2. I had a queries about the Interceptor return code.

1) what is the return type of a interceptor/custom interceptor? Will it be only success or what happen if i return false/failure/any string (in case of custom interceptor).

2) purpose of action invocation ?

3) Is our actions or interceptors are thread safe?

Thanks for your kind support in advance

Comment: Have you read documentation? http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/interceptors.html

Comment: No Ligios, I have verified the stuff under this link. It seems i can find good stuff here ..Thanks ...

Comment: I was the editor of your question, you are referring to the comment that is from Aleksandr M ...

Answer (score 0):

1) An Interceptor can

- continue to the next Interceptor, or to the Action if it is the last, with `return invocation.invoke();`
- return a Global Result directyl, eg. `return "globalError";` ,
- return a local Action Result [after having read the ResultConfig object like this](http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/can-we-access-an-actions-result.html))

returning a result instead of proceeding to the next Interceptor will break the flow before reaching the Action.

2) [From Action Invocation Javadoc](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/xwork-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/ActionInvocation.html):

> An ActionInvocation represents the execution state of an Action. It holds the Interceptors and the Action instance. By repeated re-entrant execution of the invoke() method, initially by the ActionProxy, then by the Interceptors, the Interceptors are all executed, and then the Action and the Result.

3)

- **Actions are thread-safe** (because they're ThreadLocal)
- **Interceptor are NOT thread-safe**